# I need to add the total of every 3 rows

Tags: excel-2010

I need to add the total of every 3 rows.... so I need total of rows 1- 3 then total of 4-6 then total of 7-9 and so on and need to do this for over 400 rows...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you wish to sum is in Column A and the summed data will be in Column B (with headers for both columns) you can do the following:

On `B4` enter `=SUM(A2:A4)`

Then select `B2:B4` and drag to copy the contents down your range of data.

This will give you the sum of every three rows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list starts at A1, you can use the following starting at B3 and carrying it down the list. Then set B1 and B2 to 0 and filter out all zeros.

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,SUM(A1,A2,A3),0)
```

This determines if the row number is divisible evenly by 3, if it is it returns the sum of that row and the previous 2, otherwise it returns zero.

If you have a header row, you can change it to and set zeros for B2 and B3 and start this on B4

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,3)=0,SUM(A2,A3,A4),0)
```